# How can I make this code if and else?

Tags: php, html

How can I make this code if and else?
If 'Rental' is true do this.... else... do the false bit. I'm getting lost in the PHP tags.

```
<?php 
    if( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Rental', true) ) { 
?>
<li style="padding:3px 10px; line-height: 18px; height:34px"><strong><?php _e( 'Rental Potential / Actual', 'spanglishwebs' ) ?>:</strong> <?php 
    $priceWithoutFormat = get_custom_field('Rental');
    $priceWithFormat = number_format($priceWithoutFormat, 0, ',', '.');
    echo $priceWithFormat; 
?>&euro;/Annual </li>
<?php 
    }
    if( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Rental', false) ) { 
?>
<li>Rental Potential / Actual: N/A</li>
<?php 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: *Im getting lost in the php tags.* format your code and you're not lost

Comment: You have mixed up your code..now its totally broken!

Comment: I generally find it much cleaner to put php tags at the beginning and end, and echo or print from within the tags when I want html output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Rental', true)) { ?>
    <li style="padding:3px 10px; line-height: 18px; height:34px">
    <strong><?php _e('Rental Potential / Actual', 'spanglishwebs') ?>:</strong> 
    <?php
        $priceWithoutFormat = get_custom_field('Rental');
        $priceWithFormat = number_format($priceWithoutFormat, 0, ',', '.');
        echo $priceWithFormat; ?>&euro;/Annual
    </li>
<?php } else { ?>
    <li>Rental Potential / Actual: N/A</li>
<?php } ?>
```

Try if it works, your code is really messy...

Comment: That works, thank you very much. I will see if I can clean up the code. :D